# Check if cell in dataframe is NaN, if it is, iterate to the next cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a nested dataframe that I need to `explode()`.

I'm imagining the code will be something like this?
I would like to avoid using the explicit column names in the code if possible since then the code would break if the column names were to change.

```py
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    if df.isnull(df.iloc[:, [i]]):
        pass
    else:
        df.iloc[:, [i]].apply(pd.Series)
```

This is my dataframe:

```json
{
  "Segment": {
    "CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedCashEquivalentsPeriodIncreaseDecreaseIncludingExchangeRateEffect": np.nan,
    "CommonStockCapitalSharesReservedForFutureIssuance": np.nan,
    "CommonStockParOrStatedValuePerShare": np.nan,
    "CommonStockSharesAuthorized": np.nan,
    "CommonStockSharesIssued": np.nan,
    "CommonStockSharesOutstanding": np.nan
  },
  "USD": {
    "CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedCashEquivalentsPeriodIncreaseDecreaseIncludingExchangeRateEffect": [
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-22-002008",
        "end": "2019-12-31",
        "filed": "2022-02-24",
        "form": "10-K",
        "fp": "FY",
        "frame": "CY2019",
        "fy": 2021,
        "start": "2019-01-01",
        "val": -19846000
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-000956",
        "end": "2020-06-30",
        "filed": "2021-08-05",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q2",
        "fy": 2021,
        "start": "2020-01-01",
        "val": 9247000
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-003110",
        "end": "2020-09-30",
        "filed": "2021-11-04",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q3",
        "fy": 2021,
        "start": "2020-01-01",
        "val": 33446000
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-22-002008",
        "end": "2020-12-31",
        "filed": "2022-02-24",
        "form": "10-K",
        "fp": "FY",
        "frame": "CY2020",
        "fy": 2021,
        "start": "2020-01-01",
        "val": 17835000
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-22-007876",
        "end": "2021-03-31",
        "filed": "2022-05-05",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q1",
        "frame": "CY2021Q1",
        "fy": 2022,
        "start": "2021-01-01",
        "val": 7308000
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-000956",
        "end": "2021-06-30",
        "filed": "2021-08-05",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q2",
        "fy": 2021,
        "start": "2021-01-01",
        "val": 823291000
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-003110",
        "end": "2021-09-30",
        "filed": "2021-11-04",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q3",
        "fy": 2021,
        "start": "2021-01-01",
        "val": 545641000
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-22-002008",
        "end": "2021-12-31",
        "filed": "2022-02-24",
        "form": "10-K",
        "fp": "FY",
        "frame": "CY2021",
        "fy": 2021,
        "start": "2021-01-01",
        "val": 1338876000
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-22-007876",
        "end": "2022-03-31",
        "filed": "2022-05-05",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q1",
        "frame": "CY2022Q1",
        "fy": 2022,
        "start": "2022-01-01",
        "val": -328343000
      }
    ],
    "CommonStockCapitalSharesReservedForFutureIssuance": np.nan,
    "CommonStockParOrStatedValuePerShare": np.nan,
    "CommonStockSharesAuthorized": np.nan,
    "CommonStockSharesIssued": np.nan,
    "CommonStockSharesOutstanding": np.nan
  },
  "USD/shares": {
    "CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedCashEquivalentsPeriodIncreaseDecreaseIncludingExchangeRateEffect": np.nan,
    "CommonStockCapitalSharesReservedForFutureIssuance": np.nan,
    "CommonStockParOrStatedValuePerShare": [
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-000956",
        "end": "2020-12-31",
        "filed": "2021-08-05",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q2",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 1e-05
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-003110",
        "end": "2020-12-31",
        "filed": "2021-11-04",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q3",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 1e-05
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-22-002008",
        "end": "2020-12-31",
        "filed": "2022-02-24",
        "form": "10-K",
        "fp": "FY",
        "frame": "CY2020Q4I",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 1e-05
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-000956",
        "end": "2021-06-30",
        "filed": "2021-08-05",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q2",
        "frame": "CY2021Q2I",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 1e-05
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-003110",
        "end": "2021-09-30",
        "filed": "2021-11-04",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q3",
        "frame": "CY2021Q3I",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 1e-05
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-22-002008",
        "end": "2021-12-31",
        "filed": "2022-02-24",
        "form": "10-K",
        "fp": "FY",
        "frame": "CY2021Q4I",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 1e-05
      }
    ],
    "CommonStockSharesAuthorized": np.nan,
    "CommonStockSharesIssued": np.nan,
    "CommonStockSharesOutstanding": np.nan
  },
  "pure": {
    "CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedCashEquivalentsPeriodIncreaseDecreaseIncludingExchangeRateEffect": np.nan,
    "CommonStockCapitalSharesReservedForFutureIssuance": np.nan,
    "CommonStockParOrStatedValuePerShare": np.nan,
    "CommonStockSharesAuthorized": np.nan,
    "CommonStockSharesIssued": np.nan,
    "CommonStockSharesOutstanding": np.nan
  },
  "shares": {
    "CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedCashEquivalentsPeriodIncreaseDecreaseIncludingExchangeRateEffect": np.nan,
    "CommonStockCapitalSharesReservedForFutureIssuance": [
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-000956",
        "end": "2020-12-31",
        "filed": "2021-08-05",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q2",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 191849299
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-003110",
        "end": "2020-12-31",
        "filed": "2021-11-04",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q3",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 191849299
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-22-002008",
        "end": "2020-12-31",
        "filed": "2022-02-24",
        "form": "10-K",
        "fp": "FY",
        "frame": "CY2020Q4I",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 191849299
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-000956",
        "end": "2021-06-30",
        "filed": "2021-08-05",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q2",
        "frame": "CY2021Q2I",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 118286387
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-003110",
        "end": "2021-09-30",
        "filed": "2021-11-04",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q3",
        "frame": "CY2021Q3I",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 113722500
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-22-002008",
        "end": "2021-12-31",
        "filed": "2022-02-24",
        "form": "10-K",
        "fp": "FY",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 106320711
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-22-007876",
        "end": "2021-12-31",
        "filed": "2022-05-05",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q1",
        "frame": "CY2021Q4I",
        "fy": 2022,
        "val": 106320711
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-22-007876",
        "end": "2022-03-31",
        "filed": "2022-05-05",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q1",
        "frame": "CY2022Q1I",
        "fy": 2022,
        "val": 116393943
      }
    ],
    "CommonStockParOrStatedValuePerShare": np.nan,
    "CommonStockSharesAuthorized": [
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-000956",
        "end": "2020-12-31",
        "filed": "2021-08-05",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q2",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 323000000
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-003110",
        "end": "2020-12-31",
        "filed": "2021-11-04",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q3",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 323000000
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-22-002008",
        "end": "2020-12-31",
        "filed": "2022-02-24",
        "form": "10-K",
        "fp": "FY",
        "frame": "CY2020Q4I",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 323000000
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-000956",
        "end": "2021-06-30",
        "filed": "2021-08-05",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q2",
        "frame": "CY2021Q2I",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 0
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-003110",
        "end": "2021-09-30",
        "filed": "2021-11-04",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q3",
        "frame": "CY2021Q3I",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 0
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-22-002008",
        "end": "2021-12-31",
        "filed": "2022-02-24",
        "form": "10-K",
        "fp": "FY",
        "frame": "CY2021Q4I",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 0
      }
    ],
    "CommonStockSharesIssued": [
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-000956",
        "end": "2020-12-31",
        "filed": "2021-08-05",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q2",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 109447843
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-003110",
        "end": "2020-12-31",
        "filed": "2021-11-04",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q3",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 109447843
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-22-002008",
        "end": "2020-12-31",
        "filed": "2022-02-24",
        "form": "10-K",
        "fp": "FY",
        "frame": "CY2020Q4I",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 109447843
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-000956",
        "end": "2021-06-30",
        "filed": "2021-08-05",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q2",
        "frame": "CY2021Q2I",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 0
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-003110",
        "end": "2021-09-30",
        "filed": "2021-11-04",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q3",
        "frame": "CY2021Q3I",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 0
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-22-002008",
        "end": "2021-12-31",
        "filed": "2022-02-24",
        "form": "10-K",
        "fp": "FY",
        "frame": "CY2021Q4I",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 0
      }
    ],
    "CommonStockSharesOutstanding": [
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-000956",
        "end": "2020-12-31",
        "filed": "2021-08-05",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q2",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 109447843
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-003110",
        "end": "2020-12-31",
        "filed": "2021-11-04",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q3",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 109447843
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-22-002008",
        "end": "2020-12-31",
        "filed": "2022-02-24",
        "form": "10-K",
        "fp": "FY",
        "frame": "CY2020Q4I",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 109447843
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-000956",
        "end": "2021-06-30",
        "filed": "2021-08-05",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q2",
        "frame": "CY2021Q2I",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 0
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-21-003110",
        "end": "2021-09-30",
        "filed": "2021-11-04",
        "form": "10-Q",
        "fp": "Q3",
        "frame": "CY2021Q3I",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 0
      },
      {
        "accn": "0000950170-22-002008",
        "end": "2021-12-31",
        "filed": "2022-02-24",
        "form": "10-K",
        "fp": "FY",
        "frame": "CY2021Q4I",
        "fy": 2021,
        "val": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just explode it with pandas' explode function?

Comment: `apply` works for the whole column. You can define a function that does whatever you want (including doing nothing to NaNs) and then just "apply" it to the column. That's a lot faster than iterating through each row. I can't write it since I don't get what do you want to do.

Comment: ? It is a dataframe, just paste the code into `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)`

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly `from numpy import nan` easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a DataFrame, You have a complicated nested dictionary. We can try to make sense of it like this:

Every 2nd level value that's a list can be made into a DataFrame, but we still probably want to know where it came from, so we'll give it a MultiIndex with that information.

```
dfs = []
names = ['category1', 'category2']
for i, x in data.items():
    for j, y in x.items():
        if isinstance(y, list):
            index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(i, j)]*len(y), names=names)
            dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(y, index=index))
        # Optional, if you want the blank values as well:
        #else:
            #index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(i, j)], names=names)
            #dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(index=index))

df = pd.concat(dfs)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                                                               accn         end       filed  form  fp      frame    fy       start           val
category1  category2
USD        CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedC...  0000950170-22-002008  2019-12-31  2022-02-24  10-K  FY     CY2019  2021  2019-01-01 -1.984600e+07
           CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedC...  0000950170-21-000956  2020-06-30  2021-08-05  10-Q  Q2        NaN  2021  2020-01-01  9.247000e+06
           CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedC...  0000950170-21-003110  2020-09-30  2021-11-04  10-Q  Q3        NaN  2021  2020-01-01  3.344600e+07
           CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedC...  0000950170-22-002008  2020-12-31  2022-02-24  10-K  FY     CY2020  2021  2020-01-01  1.783500e+07
           CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedC...  0000950170-22-007876  2021-03-31  2022-05-05  10-Q  Q1   CY2021Q1  2022  2021-01-01  7.308000e+06
           CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedC...  0000950170-21-000956  2021-06-30  2021-08-05  10-Q  Q2        NaN  2021  2021-01-01  8.232910e+08
           CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedC...  0000950170-21-003110  2021-09-30  2021-11-04  10-Q  Q3        NaN  2021  2021-01-01  5.456410e+08
           CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedC...  0000950170-22-002008  2021-12-31  2022-02-24  10-K  FY     CY2021  2021  2021-01-01  1.338876e+09
           CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedC...  0000950170-22-007876  2022-03-31  2022-05-05  10-Q  Q1   CY2022Q1  2022  2022-01-01 -3.283430e+08
USD/shares CommonStockParOrStatedValuePerShare                 0000950170-21-000956  2020-12-31  2021-08-05  10-Q  Q2        NaN  2021         NaN  1.000000e-05
           CommonStockParOrStatedValuePerShare                 0000950170-21-003110  2020-12-31  2021-11-04  10-Q  Q3        NaN  2021         NaN  1.000000e-05
           CommonStockParOrStatedValuePerShare                 0000950170-22-002008  2020-12-31  2022-02-24  10-K  FY  CY2020Q4I  2021         NaN  1.000000e-05
           CommonStockParOrStatedValuePerShare                 0000950170-21-000956  2021-06-30  2021-08-05  10-Q  Q2  CY2021Q2I  2021         NaN  1.000000e-05
           CommonStockParOrStatedValuePerShare                 0000950170-21-003110  2021-09-30  2021-11-04  10-Q  Q3  CY2021Q3I  2021         NaN  1.000000e-05
           CommonStockParOrStatedValuePerShare                 0000950170-22-002008  2021-12-31  2022-02-24  10-K  FY  CY2021Q4I  2021         NaN  1.000000e-05
shares     CommonStockCapitalSharesReservedForFutureIssuance   0000950170-21-000956  2020-12-31  2021-08-05  10-Q  Q2        NaN  2021         NaN  1.918493e+08
           CommonStockCapitalSharesReservedForFutureIssuance   0000950170-21-003110  2020-12-31  2021-11-04  10-Q  Q3        NaN  2021         NaN  1.918493e+08
           CommonStockCapitalSharesReservedForFutureIssuance   0000950170-22-002008  2020-12-31  2022-02-24  10-K  FY  CY2020Q4I  2021         NaN  1.918493e+08
           CommonStockCapitalSharesReservedForFutureIssuance   0000950170-21-000956  2021-06-30  2021-08-05  10-Q  Q2  CY2021Q2I  2021         NaN  1.182864e+08
           CommonStockCapitalSharesReservedForFutureIssuance   0000950170-21-003110  2021-09-30  2021-11-04  10-Q  Q3  CY2021Q3I  2021         NaN  1.137225e+08
           CommonStockCapitalSharesReservedForFutureIssuance   0000950170-22-002008  2021-12-31  2022-02-24  10-K  FY        NaN  2021         NaN  1.063207e+08
           CommonStockCapitalSharesReservedForFutureIssuance   0000950170-22-007876  2021-12-31  2022-05-05  10-Q  Q1  CY2021Q4I  2022         NaN  1.063207e+08
           CommonStockCapitalSharesReservedForFutureIssuance   0000950170-22-007876  2022-03-31  2022-05-05  10-Q  Q1  CY2022Q1I  2022         NaN  1.163939e+08
           CommonStockSharesAuthorized                         0000950170-21-000956  2020-12-31  2021-08-05  10-Q  Q2        NaN  2021         NaN  3.230000e+08
           CommonStockSharesAuthorized                         0000950170-21-003110  2020-12-31  2021-11-04  10-Q  Q3        NaN  2021         NaN  3.230000e+08
           CommonStockSharesAuthorized                         0000950170-22-002008  2020-12-31  2022-02-24  10-K  FY  CY2020Q4I  2021         NaN  3.230000e+08
           CommonStockSharesAuthorized                         0000950170-21-000956  2021-06-30  2021-08-05  10-Q  Q2  CY2021Q2I  2021         NaN  0.000000e+00
           CommonStockSharesAuthorized                         0000950170-21-003110  2021-09-30  2021-11-04  10-Q  Q3  CY2021Q3I  2021         NaN  0.000000e+00
           CommonStockSharesAuthorized                         0000950170-22-002008  2021-12-31  2022-02-24  10-K  FY  CY2021Q4I  2021         NaN  0.000000e+00
           CommonStockSharesIssued                             0000950170-21-000956  2020-12-31  2021-08-05  10-Q  Q2        NaN  2021         NaN  1.094478e+08
           CommonStockSharesIssued                             0000950170-21-003110  2020-12-31  2021-11-04  10-Q  Q3        NaN  2021         NaN  1.094478e+08
           CommonStockSharesIssued                             0000950170-22-002008  2020-12-31  2022-02-24  10-K  FY  CY2020Q4I  2021         NaN  1.094478e+08
           CommonStockSharesIssued                             0000950170-21-000956  2021-06-30  2021-08-05  10-Q  Q2  CY2021Q2I  2021         NaN  0.000000e+00
           CommonStockSharesIssued                             0000950170-21-003110  2021-09-30  2021-11-04  10-Q  Q3  CY2021Q3I  2021         NaN  0.000000e+00
           CommonStockSharesIssued                             0000950170-22-002008  2021-12-31  2022-02-24  10-K  FY  CY2021Q4I  2021         NaN  0.000000e+00
           CommonStockSharesOutstanding                        0000950170-21-000956  2020-12-31  2021-08-05  10-Q  Q2        NaN  2021         NaN  1.094478e+08
           CommonStockSharesOutstanding                        0000950170-21-003110  2020-12-31  2021-11-04  10-Q  Q3        NaN  2021         NaN  1.094478e+08
           CommonStockSharesOutstanding                        0000950170-22-002008  2020-12-31  2022-02-24  10-K  FY  CY2020Q4I  2021         NaN  1.094478e+08
           CommonStockSharesOutstanding                        0000950170-21-000956  2021-06-30  2021-08-05  10-Q  Q2  CY2021Q2I  2021         NaN  0.000000e+00
           CommonStockSharesOutstanding                        0000950170-21-003110  2021-09-30  2021-11-04  10-Q  Q3  CY2021Q3I  2021         NaN  0.000000e+00
           CommonStockSharesOutstanding                        0000950170-22-002008  2021-12-31  2022-02-24  10-K  FY  CY2021Q4I  2021         NaN  0.000000e+00
```

Output with blanks:

```
>>> print(df.head(25))
                                                                               accn         end       filed  form   fp      frame      fy       start           val
category1  category2
Segment    CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedC...                   NaN         NaN         NaN   NaN  NaN        NaN     NaN         NaN           NaN
           CommonStockCapitalSharesReservedForFutureIssuance                    NaN         NaN         NaN   NaN  NaN        NaN     NaN         NaN           NaN
           CommonStockParOrStatedValuePerShare                                  NaN         NaN         NaN   NaN  NaN        NaN     NaN         NaN           NaN
           CommonStockSharesAuthorized                                          NaN         NaN         NaN   NaN  NaN        NaN     NaN         NaN           NaN
           CommonStockSharesIssued                                              NaN         NaN         NaN   NaN  NaN        NaN     NaN         NaN           NaN
           CommonStockSharesOutstanding                                         NaN         NaN         NaN   NaN  NaN        NaN     NaN         NaN           NaN
USD        CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedC...  0000950170-22-002008  2019-12-31  2022-02-24  10-K   FY     CY2019  2021.0  2019-01-01 -1.984600e+07
           CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedC...  0000950170-21-000956  2020-06-30  2021-08-05  10-Q   Q2        NaN  2021.0  2020-01-01  9.247000e+06
           CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedC...  0000950170-21-003110  2020-09-30  2021-11-04  10-Q   Q3        NaN  2021.0  2020-01-01  3.344600e+07
           CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedC...  0000950170-22-002008  2020-12-31  2022-02-24  10-K   FY     CY2020  2021.0  2020-01-01  1.783500e+07
           CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedC...  0000950170-22-007876  2021-03-31  2022-05-05  10-Q   Q1   CY2021Q1  2022.0  2021-01-01  7.308000e+06
           CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedC...  0000950170-21-000956  2021-06-30  2021-08-05  10-Q   Q2        NaN  2021.0  2021-01-01  8.232910e+08
           CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedC...  0000950170-21-003110  2021-09-30  2021-11-04  10-Q   Q3        NaN  2021.0  2021-01-01  5.456410e+08
           CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedC...  0000950170-22-002008  2021-12-31  2022-02-24  10-K   FY     CY2021  2021.0  2021-01-01  1.338876e+09
           CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedC...  0000950170-22-007876  2022-03-31  2022-05-05  10-Q   Q1   CY2022Q1  2022.0  2022-01-01 -3.283430e+08
           CommonStockCapitalSharesReservedForFutureIssuance                    NaN         NaN         NaN   NaN  NaN        NaN     NaN         NaN           NaN
           CommonStockParOrStatedValuePerShare                                  NaN         NaN         NaN   NaN  NaN        NaN     NaN         NaN           NaN
           CommonStockSharesAuthorized                                          NaN         NaN         NaN   NaN  NaN        NaN     NaN         NaN           NaN
           CommonStockSharesIssued                                              NaN         NaN         NaN   NaN  NaN        NaN     NaN         NaN           NaN
           CommonStockSharesOutstanding                                         NaN         NaN         NaN   NaN  NaN        NaN     NaN         NaN           NaN
USD/shares CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedC...                   NaN         NaN         NaN   NaN  NaN        NaN     NaN         NaN           NaN
           CommonStockCapitalSharesReservedForFutureIssuance                    NaN         NaN         NaN   NaN  NaN        NaN     NaN         NaN           NaN
           CommonStockParOrStatedValuePerShare                 0000950170-21-000956  2020-12-31  2021-08-05  10-Q   Q2        NaN  2021.0         NaN  1.000000e-05
           CommonStockParOrStatedValuePerShare                 0000950170-21-003110  2020-12-31  2021-11-04  10-Q   Q3        NaN  2021.0         NaN  1.000000e-05
           CommonStockParOrStatedValuePerShare                 0000950170-22-002008  2020-12-31  2022-02-24  10-K   FY  CY2020Q4I  2021.0         NaN  1.000000e-05
```

Comment: Well the screwed up Dataframe originally came like this, originated from the SEC website. But looks promising I will give that a shot and report back!

Comment: @Katsu I attempted to simplify my logic and explanation, along with giving you the opportunity to name the levels.